# Gradle publish depending on custom task using Kotlin dsl

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm switching from groovy to Kotlin dsl (build.gradle.kts) for Gradle builds. My publish artifact depends on my custom task. And I do not understand how to make this dependency in Kotlin dsl.

Original groovy code that I like to migrate to Kotlin dsl:

```
publish.dependsOn doSomething
```

Tasks that I am trying to chain:

```
val doSomething by tasks.creating(ShellExec::class) {
    command = "./do-something"
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            ...
        }
    }

    publications {
        register("mavenJava", MavenPublication::class) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Can do it like this

```
tasks.withType<PublishToMavenRepository> {
  dependsOn("doSomething")
}
```